# Пропал сетевой адаптер из списка, но остаётся видимым с консоли

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless

Такая проблема:

Беспроводной адаптер Qualcomm Atheros AR956x Wireless Network Adapter просто пропал из сетевых адаптеров и сетевых подключений после того, как отсоединил его от роутера и вынул батарею из ноутбука.

Так всё дело в том, что в диспетчере устройств его нет, а вот здесь он есть:

[image: netcfg]

Драйверы не ставит: пишет, что устройство не подключено.
Уже такое когда-то было, но не помню как решил.

Answer (score 0):

Если кому-то пригодится: включаете вид - показать скрытые устройства - удаляем сетевой адаптер (с восклицательным знаком или без) - перезагружаетесь.
Если не помогло: вставляем батарею и отключаем от питания - загружаемся - снова выключаем - достаём батарею и подключаем питание - загружаемся - всё работает ( или в другой последовательности - важно, перезагрузить цепочку питания ). Ну это, конечно же для ноутбука, хотя для стационарного можно сделать похожие манипуляции. И помните: лезть в плату последнее дело! Хотя переподключение платы, возможно, может решить эту проблему сразу.